# The program 'rails' is currently not installed

Tags: 12.04, rails

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on VirtualBox.

I installed rvm, ruby and rails following [this tutorial](http://blog.sudobits.com/2012/05/02/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/).

But when I restart, I am getting this error:

```
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

And after that, when I again try `gem install rails` I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /var/lib/gems
```

And there is no `gems` folder under `/var/lib/`.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gem install rails` needs to be run as root since `/var/lib/gems` should be 0644 or something. Therefore, use:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple ways to install rails, one is straight from apt and another from ruby gems.

```
apt-get install ruby-rails-3.2
```

This isn't the best way to install rails, it's better to have ruby gems handle rails for you. First make sure that ruby and ruby gems are up to date

```
$ ruby -v && gem -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
1.8.23
```

Run

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

To get the latest versions.
NOTE: You got his error

```
PERMISSION DENIED
```

Run the exact command with sudo prepended to the command so

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Should be the correct way to install rails.

Be careful when using the sudo command, make sure you know what you are doing. As the saying goes "With great power comes great responsibility" and sudo is no exception.

Comment: Using `sudo` every time a command gives PERMISSION DENIED isn't a good idea. Some commands do this for a reason if something shouldn;t be tampered with, others that access files (with mangled permissions) in a personal folder might mangle them even more.

Comment: I agree and that's why I included a note about being careful with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

This issue arose for me when working on an already setup **Ubuntu 18.04** server with **Ruby 2.5.0** and **Rails 5.2** installed.

The error output was:

> The program 'rails' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt install ruby-railties

The issue is simply caused by the rails executable not being globally accessible by programs.

**Here's how I solved it**

**Note:** If you are working on a production server, endeavour to make a backup of your database before trying out the solution below to avoid data loss.

For my case, my version manager was **rbenv** and not **rvm**

Re-install **rbenv** itself. Clone the **rbenv** repository from GitHub into the directory ~/.rbenv:

`git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv`

Next, add `~/.rbenv/bin` to your `$PATH` so that you can use the rbenv command line utility. Do this by altering your ~/.bashrc file so that it affects future login sessions:

`echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc`

Then add the command eval "$(rbenv init -)" to your ~/.bashrc file so rbenv loads automatically:

`echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc`

Next, apply the changes you made to your ~/.bashrc file to your current shell session:

`source ~/.bashrc`

Verify that **rbenv** is set up properly by using the type command, which will display more information about the **rbenv** command:

`type rbenv`

Your terminal window will display the following:

```
rbenv is a function
rbenv ()
{
    local command;
    command="${1:-}";
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        shift;
    fi;
    case "$command" in
        rehash | shell)
            eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")"
        ;;
        *)
            command rbenv "$command" "$@"
        ;;
    esac
}
```

If everything worked right, running the command below will display the versions of **Ruby** and **Rails** previously installed on your machine:

```
ruby -v
rails -v
```

Else, run a fresh installation of **Ruby** and **Rails** on your machine.

That's all

**I hope this helps**